# How to check if a symbol is a register in a TASM macro?

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-16, tasm

Is there any way to check if a symbol is a number or a register or a memory location?

```
if AX is a 16 bit register
  Do this
else
 Do that
```

I'll be using it in a macro to check the symbol refers to a 8-bit or 16-bit location + if it is a specific register or not...

Is there something like an assemble-time check?

Comment: Look up `SYMTYPE` and `.TYPE` in _Turbo Assembler User's Guide_. That seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael! However my problem still isn't solved. My 16-bit TASM doesn't know what SYMTYPE and there is an macro called as .type, but it can only differentiate between registers (returns 30H) and immediate values (returns 24H). It returns the same value for AX AH SI BX. Is there some other way out or am I missing out on something?

Comment: MOV AX, .type AH

Comment: Is there some assemble time way to conditionally solve my problem...So if .type AX == 0024H then perform the register operation else do that... Or something with CMP without a register..

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to check what `AX` is, so I'm assuming that you're actually dealing with a macro parameter that could be `AX` or anything else. So `IF (.TYPE param) EQ 30h` would evaluate to true at assembly-time if the parameter is a register. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to differentiate between different register sizes though. You might need a bunch of string comparisons for that.